table.remove() in lua 5.4 is strange
I try to remove nil from table, but table.remove() in lua 5.4 is strange:
a = { nil, -0.0227, nil, -0.1157, nil, 0.0191, 0.1476, nil, nil,nil, nil, 0.1714, nil, -0.0681};

print("table a size:",#a);

tb_size = #a;
for j = tb_size,1,-1 do

    print(j,"==", a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],"tb size:",#a)

    if not a[j] then
        print("remove:",j,a[j]);
        table.remove(a,j);
        print(j,"--", a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],"tb size:",#a);
    end --if

end --for

this code alwasy report error: bad argument #1 to 'remove' (position out of bounds), the table size will suddenly　become 7 from 14.
enter image description here
I try to remove nil from table , but table.remove() do not work , always report "position out of bounds", what is wrong ??

The behavior of table.remove depends on the result of the length operator (#), which can be any non-nil index that is followed by a nil index. For performance reasons, Lua will not scan an entire table to find the largest non-nil index. In order to get well-defined results from # and the table library functions, you have to construct your arrays without nils in them.
Relevant docs:

table.remove
The Length Operator


lua5.1 work fine, but in lua5.4 I have to  copy a new table without nil.
